# How to authenticate Microsoft Azure API's using username & Password

Tags: azure, authentication, microsoft-graph-api

I want to get the access token using Microsoft azure username & password.
Is there any API or flow available by using username & password I will get access token.

Comment: You could use [ROPC flow](https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-dotnet/wiki/Username-Password-Authentication) to get access token.

Comment: @JoeyCai This flow is available on .net desktop and .net core. I am required in Java or any rest API using that I can develop in java

Comment: Why not use a service principal with client id + client secret?

Comment: @ShreyaGupta All the auth flow's are platform independent. You can implement it from any language and framework. [Please refer to this docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-client-creds-grant-flow)

Comment: @JoeyCai I don't think Microsoft azure supports this kind of authentication "Java restful webservices with HTTP basic authentication."

Comment: @MdFaridUddinKiron yes currently I am using Oauth2 authentication.

Comment: @MdFaridUddinKiron but now I want to user to only provide me username & password.

Comment: @ShreyaGupta In that case you could try `ROPC` as shown already where users need to submit `UserName` and `Password` try that and let me know if you encounter any more problem.

Comment: @MdFaridUddinKiron In ROPC I am getting the following error."error": "invalid_grant",
    "error_description": "AADSTS50056: Invalid or missing password: password does not exist in the directory for this user.\r\nTrace ID: 15b934dffd98-a949-4283-b6d1-33108ae27300\r\nCorrelation ID: bd7edf53fdfdf-d2f4-4249-901f-12026c5f498c\r\nTimestamp: 2020-03-09 10:01:38Z",

Comment: Include your token request on your question so that it would be easy to investigate

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As per your comment, please follow the detail steps:

```
https://login.microsoftonline.com/YourTenant.onmicrosoft.com/oauth2/v2.0/token

client_id:b603c7be_Client_id_e61f925
scope:https://graph.microsoft.com/.default
client_secret:NpmwO/KDJ_client_secret:NpmwO_W0kWf1SbnL
username:tenentUser.onmicrosoft.com
password:YourUserPassword
grant_type:password
```

See the screen shot:

[image]

I am getting token as expected

***`Step: 1`***

[image]

***`Step: 2`***

[image]

***`Step: 3`***

[image]

***`Note:`***

> 1. Requested token user must be a tenant user for example `YourUser@Yourtenant.onmicrosoft.com`
> 2. User password must be correct that you are suing to token request.
> 3. Make sure your user belong to azure portal on your tenant
> 4. Your Client Id belongs to that tenant
> 5. Application secret is valid or not expired.

For more information you could refer [Official document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth-ropc)

Feel free to share still you are having problem.

Comment: Hi should it work on 2-factor authentication azure accounts?

Comment: No you are not allowed to use  `multi-factor authentication (MFA)` on `ROPC`. system would blocked you. That's why its not recommended.

Comment: Additionally, `personal accounts` is not allowed , your email must be tenant specific.

Comment: I am geeting the error code 50056 code... As my account uses MFA. As the Id is name.organization.com

Comment: As per Microsoft convention you cannot use `ROPC` if you have `MFA` enable. In that case `Client_credential` protocol will be best fit.

Answer (score 2):

> I am required in Java or any rest API using that I can develop in java

Microsoft identity platform supports the [OAuth 2.0 Resource Owner Password Credentials (ROPC) grant](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth-ropc), which allows an application to sign in the user by directly handling their password.

Send below request in java and after successfully it will return access token.

```
POST {tenant}/oauth2/v2.0/token
Host: login.microsoftonline.com
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded

client_id=6731de76-14a6-49ae-97bc-6eba6914391e
&scope=user.read%20openid%20profile%20offline_access
&username=MyUsername@myTenant.com
&password=SuperS3cret
&grant_type=password
```

> **Microsoft recommends you do not use the ROPC flow.** In most scenarios, more secure alternatives are available and recommended. This flow requires a very high degree of trust in the application, and carries risks which are not present in other flows. You should only use this flow when other more secure flows can't be used.